# Is it possible to write a C# template class<T> that can be substituted in any context where T is valid?

Tags: c#

I wrote `ObservableValue<T>` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for value types as a compliment to the .NET class `ObservableCollection<T>`.

```
class ObservableValue<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private T value;
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler eh;

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged {
        add { eh += value; }
        remove { eh -= value; }
    }

    public T Value {
        get { return value; }
        set {
            this.value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged() {
        if (eh != null)
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
    }
}
```

However, to use this class one must bind to `ObservableValue<T>.Value` instead of just `ObservableValue<T>`. Is it possible to write some magic code to enable `ObservableValue<T>` to be used in any context where `T` is valid?

Comment: Have you tried implementing converion operators like `public static explicit operator T(ObservableValue<T> v)
{
    return v.Value;
}`

Comment: @Blablablaster It should be implicit, not explicit, because otherwise the users would need to add a cast instead of `.Value`, which beats the purpose of adding the operator.

Comment: @Blablablaster Yes, I have. See my comment on dasblinkenlight's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do it for *any* context: specifically, it is not possible to make it so that you could pass `ObservableValue<T>` to methods with `ref` or `out` parameters of type `T`.

However, you can come a little closer by defining an implicit [*conversion operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/85w54y0a.aspx) from `ObservableValue<T>` to `T`, letting the users pass instances of `ObservableValue<T>` to methods that take `T` by value, or assign `ObservableValue<T>` to variables of type `T` without referencing `.Value` explicitly:

```
public static implicit operator T(ObservableValue<T> ot) {
    return ot.Value;
}
```

Of course once an `ObservableValue<T>` is used in the context where `T` is expected, it loses its observable behavior: no events will be triggered, and the original `ObservableValue<T>` object would not be modified.

Comment: Implicit conversion operators are static so all the event handlers would be lost.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions Good point - I mentioned it in the edit. Thanks!